# How to delete last observations from rows in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe like so:

```
df <- data.frame("date" = c('2018','2019','2020'), 
                 "var1" = c(21,15,47), 
                 "var2" = c(0.24,0.43,0.87), 
                 "var3" = c(0.23,0.35,NA), 
                 "var4" = c(0.64,NA,NA), 
                 "var5" = c(NA,NA,NA)
                 )
```

How can I delete the last two observations in every row before the NA value?
Variables `date` and `var1` should be intact.

```
df_want <- data.frame("date" = c('2018','2019','2020'), 
                 "var1" = c(21,15,47), 
                 "var2" = c(0.24,NA,NA), 
                 "var3" = c(NA,NA,NA), 
                 "var4" = c(NA,NA,NA), 
                 "var5" = c(NA,NA,NA)
)
```

Comment: Easiest would be `df[2:3, 3:6 ] <- NA` (bit of a hack job) ,  but the "every row after the NA value" wasn't entirely clear to me. Also what's with the date as factor? Not judging.

Comment: You say "observations in every row", however since usually row = observation, it's hard to understand what exactly you want. Do you want to delete rows, columns or something else?

Comment: @horseoftheyear I meant "before" the NA.

Comment: @Liudvikas Akelis I thought that observation=value. I want to delete just the values, not entire row or column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is a for loop:

```
for(i in seq(1,nrow(df))){
  y <- min(which(is.na(df[i,])))
  z <- max(y,which(colnames(df) == "var1") + 3)
  if (!is.infinite(y)) df[i,(z-2):ncol(df)] <- NA
}
df
  date var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1 2018   21 0.24   NA   NA   NA
2 2019   15   NA   NA   NA   NA
3 2020   47   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: it works, but what if the first row don't have NA (row 1 - var5), in your code ```min(which(is.na(df[i,])))```  returns ```inf```?

Comment: It make an error, as you probably noticed, but the data is not changed. That is why the conditional `if (!is.infinite(y))` is there. You can just ignore the error, I am taking advantage of that fact.